# Access Api service using Ionic2 provider

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, restful-url

Can you tell me why I cannot access API service? It is working fine when I type it either on the browser or Postman.Why is it not working with ionic2 provider?

**Provider:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EventData {
  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  getEventList(): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://mylink.com/admin/index.php?route=api/event')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

**Exception:**

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 302 Found for
>   URL: https://www.mylink.com/admin/index.php?route=api/event
>   ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
>   IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:58 next @
>   application_ref.js:348 schedulerFn @ async.js:93
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223 SafeSubscriber.next @
>   Subscriber.js:172 Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125 Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:89 Subject.next @ Subject.js:55 EventEmitter.emit @
>   async.js:79 NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333 onHandleError @
>   ng_zone.js:294 t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3 e.runTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 invoke @ polyfills.js:3

**Update:**

```
 getEventList(): any {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://mylink.com/admin/index.php?route=api/event')
        .map(res => {
          console.log(res.headers.get('Location'));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers,null,2));
          return res.json();
        })
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
```

**Heder detail**

[image]

**Postman Headers:**

```
Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →2811
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Tue, 14 Mar 2017 02:31:50 GMT
Expires →Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Apache
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.6.26
```

Comment: are you getting the same headers in postman as well? then am not sure.

Comment: please see the postman headers.On postman it shows json data even though it's having 302 error.any idea? @suraj

Comment: I think it is redirecting and giving headers of final response. Havent seen something like this for mobile app...worst case you can try using inAppBrowser? its a weird idea..

Comment: what can I do here? @suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response 302 is a redirect to a different URL. For more explanation regarding the response itself check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973098/what-does-http-1-1-302-mean-exactly) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356838/how-does-http-302-work).
In case of browsers, they handle the redirection directly.
For your response if it is not possible to alter in the server side, you could get the redirect location in `response.headers.location`.

```
 return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://mylink.com/admin/index.php?route=api/event')
        .map(res => {console.log(res.headers.get('Location'));return res.json();})
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
```

Comment: it gives this error here `res.headers.location`.compile time error: `Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Headers'`.do you know why?

Comment: Location should be a property in headers..let me edit the answer

Comment: still the same error.please see the final code on Update section.

Comment: can you add the log for `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers,null,2))`?

Comment: should be there..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

Comment: no luck yet.now it gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error.please see the update.

Comment: ok.. try printing directly `console.log(res.headers)`. Check if you have location there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137980/discussion-between-suraj-and-sampath).

Comment: generally the redirection is handled by browser.. not sure of how it should be _handled_ at server side..Since it works in browser the location is clearly being returned.

Comment: please see the `Heder detail` on my post.

Comment: may be an issue on my endpoint.now all are working fine.Thanks for the support.Cheers :)