# scala routes setting (redirect)

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework, routes

I want to redirect to website "www.xxx.com" when access to localhost:9000.

environment is scala and play-framework.

routes file setting is below

```
 GET        /                      controllers.HomeController.index
```

controllers

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._

/**
  * A very small controller that renders a home page.
  */
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html index())
  }
}
```

This is the screenshot: localhost:9000.
[localhost:9000 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08lc7.jpg)

How to redirect to "www.xxx.com" when access to localhost:9000?
　　　　　　　　　　　　please advice me.

Comment: 302 redirect ? And browser will take care of doing it right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356838/how-does-http-302-work

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.0/api/play/mvc/results/Redirect.html#Redirect-java.lang.String-

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Default.scala

Comment: it works! Thank you!!  GET        /                      controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://www.google.com")

Comment: can you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing this one for redirect on your route.

```
controllers.Default.redirect(to = "http://www.google.com")
```