# Load testing an Flask API that requires login through Okta

Tags: python, flask, load-testing, okta, k6

We are implementing some major changes to our API (one of them being the addition of web sockets) and I wanted to perform some tests, including load testing, to ensure that they won't cause any issues before being deployed. I've been trying out some different tools for load tests, including jmeter, locust and k6. I'm leaning towards k6 because I like the documentation and the fact that you write the tests in code with JavaScript.

But I'm running into a bit of a wall. I plan to run these tests on a deployed test environment. We use okta for authentication, so in order to even access the API the virtual user would need to be authenticated. There probably isn't a need to actually log in the virtual users (correct me if I'm wrong!), I would just need a way to authenticate the user in some way or another. Then I can run my http request and socket tests.

So the main question is, how do people normally deal with a scenario like this? I figure this problem must have come up before, and I'd love to hear the general strategy for bypassing authentication for load testing. For more context, our API runs on a flask server, and here is the logic for the login process via okta2.0:

```py
@app.route("/saml/sso/login", methods=['POST'])
def idp_initiated():
    """
    Initiates the Okta SAML connection via *POST* s to ``/saml/sso/login``

    .. note::

        If a user in a SAML assertion isn't in the user store, we create that user first, then log them in.
        This is what as known as "Just In Time (JIT) provisioning".

    """
    logging.debug('IDP initiated')
    saml_client = get_saml_client()
    authn_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(
        request.form['SAMLResponse'],
        entity.BINDING_HTTP_POST
    )
    authn_response.get_identity()
    user_info = authn_response.get_subject()
    login = user_info.text

    # This is what as known as "Just In Time (JIT) provisioning".
    # What that means is that, if a user in a SAML assertion
    # isn't in the user store, we create that user first, then log them in

    logging.debug('Adding Okta info to Session')
    session.permanent = True
    session['saml_attributes'] = {}
    for attr in authn_response.ava:
        logging.debug('{}: {}'.format(attr, authn_response.ava[attr][0]))
        session['saml_attributes'][attr] = authn_response.ava[attr][0]

    logging.info('IDP initiated {user_id}'.format(user_id=login))
    user = libs.Auth.Auth.User(login=login)

    logging.debug('Okta info successfully added to Session')

    login_user(user)
    url = url_for('index')
    # NOTE:
    #   On a production system, the RelayState MUST be checked
    #   to make sure it doesn't contain dangerous URLs!
    # TODO: Whats this stuff mean?
    if 'RelayState' in request.form:
        url = request.form['RelayState']
    return redirect(url)

@app.route("/saml/login/")
def sp_initiated():
    """
    Logs the user in via --redacted--

    .. note:: The following is from a dev at Okta

        .. code-block:: python

            I realize I _technically_ don't need to set Cache-Control or Pragma http://stackoverflow.com/a/5494469
            However, Section 3.2.3.2 of the SAML spec suggests they are set http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf
            We set those headers here as a "belt and suspenders" approach,since enterprise environments don't always conform to RFCs


    :returns: Redirect to IdP URL

    """
    saml_client = get_saml_client()
    reqid, info = saml_client.prepare_for_authenticate()

    redirect_argument = request.args.get('redirect_url', '/')
    quoted_url = quote(redirect_argument)  # quote the URL so we don't lose any parts of a path using the hash `#` symbol
    redirect_url = None
    # Select the IdP URL to send the AuthN request to
    for key, value in info['headers']:
        if key == 'Location':
            redirect_url = value + "&RelayState={}".format(quoted_url)
    response = redirect(redirect_url, code=302)
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

I am trying to load test an API hidden behind okta authentication

Comment: I think usually you would "just" authenticate your VUs (in the `setup` method for instance). Create some test users in your system, have your k6 test log in your users and then pass the cookies, JWT or whatever token you have with the actual requests. If your tokens have short lifetimes, it might become a bit more tricky and you have to account for that (e.g. implementing refresh of the tokens).